# Enlarge letters in a tikz image

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to use a bigger font into this tikz image: I've settled the font using \LARGE but it is still way too small.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan, rounded corners] (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6,0) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (11,0) -- cycle;
\draw[green!80!black, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (11,0) -- cycle (-1,-3) rectangle (11,7);
\draw[red, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\draw[white, line width=15pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\node at (3,4.4) {\LARGE \texttt{A}};
\node at (3,2.9) {\LARGE \texttt{I}};
\node at (3,1.4) {\LARGE \texttt{S}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key `scale`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan, rounded corners] (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6,0) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (11,0) -- cycle;
\draw[green!80!black, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (11,0) -- cycle (-1,-3) rectangle (11,7);
\draw[red, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\draw[white, line width=15pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\node[scale=4] at (3,4.4) {\texttt{A}};
\node[scale=4] at (3,2.9) {\texttt{I}};
\node[scale=4] at (3,1.4) {\texttt{S}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]